# How do I apply for a French visa in Dubai?

Tags: schengen, france, nepali-citizens

My maternal uncle lives in France. He would like for me to visit. How do I go about this?

Comment: I'm assuming you live in Dubai and are a Nepali citizen?

Comment: yes  i am living in duabi and i am a nepali citizen.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you live in [Dubai](https://dubai.consulfrance.org/General-information):

> As of September 1st, 2019, all visa applications will be processed by the consular service of the Embassy of France in Abu Dhabi.
>
> Visa applicants residing in the United Arab Emirates will have the option to apply either to Dubai VFS Center, which remains open, or to the VFS Center in Abu Dhabi.

That said, all information on how to obtain a short-stay visa is [here](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/ai-je-besoin-d-un-visa?p_p_id=NeedVisaApplication_WAR_fvfoportalvisasportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&_NeedVisaApplication_WAR_fvfoportalvisasportlet_implicitModel=true):

The supporting documents to be provided are as follows:

```
Pre-requisites

    Application form dated and signed

    France-Visas receipt.

    ID photograph

    If you are not a national of your country of residence: proof that you are legally resident in that country (e.g. residence permit)

    Travel document issued fewer than 10 years ago, which will remain valid for at least three months after the planned return date and which has at least two blank pages

Purpose of travel/stay

    If applicable, proof of family relationship with the host

    Reservation of a return ticket or travel itinerary

Travel health insurance

    Travel health insurance certificate (cf FAQ)

Accommodation

    Proof of accommodation (Attestation d'accueil)

Funds

    Bank statements, pay slips, pension statements

Socio-professional situation

    Proof of socio-professional status (e.g. employment contract, certificate of employment, extract from the trade and companies’ register, school attendance certificate, proof of pension) and any documents demonstrating the applicant’s personal links to the country of residence (e.g. copy of marriage certificate, family record book).
```

I made some assumptions as to your age and length of stay, but the documents required are nonetheless the same if you are indeed traveling for a family visit.